# Let $x, y, z$ be a primitive pythagorean triple. Show that exactly two of $x^2, y^2, z^2$ are congruent mod 7

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

So, I know that if x,y, and z are a pythagorean triple, then

$x = m^2-n^2$,
$y = 2mn$,
$z = m^2+n^2$

How can I show that exactly two of $x^2, y^2, z^2$ are congruent mod 7?

Comment: Look at the squares modulo $7$, and see how they add. You don’t need the formulas you quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $x^2+y^2=z^2$.

What are the square elements modulo $7$? They are $0,1,4,2$.

So, there are $\binom4 2+4\ =10$ possibilities of (nonnecessarily disctint) pairs $x^2,y^2$  modulo $7$, check at each one, that their sum is a square element or not, and verify the claim.

(E.g. $z^2$ cannot be $0$, as neither $6,3,5$ are squares mod $7$, so, if, say $x\equiv 0\pmod7$, then $y^2\equiv z^2$. And so on..)

Comment: Do we say that $x^2, y^2, z^2$ has to be equal to a quadratic residue of 7 because those are the only values that they can be mod 7?

Comment: Well, since $x,y,z$ are integers, by definition of quadratic residue, we must have $x^2,y^2,z^2$ are quadratic residues.